# How to set color on collision object in Bullet?

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

So there I have made a nice debug drawer... And get all world objects drown... Now I want some to be drawn with special color (eg bullets player, enemies mesh representations). So how to spesify mesh color so to get it drawn on [`dynamicsWorld->getDebugDrawer()->debugDrawWorld();`](http://bulletphysics.com/ftp/pub/test/physics/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf) correctly? I cant find coloring options in [btCollisionShape](http://www.continuousphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCollisionShape.html)  nor in [btCollisionObject](http://www.continuousphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCollisionObject.html) API=( So how to set color on it?

Comment: What are CollisionShape and CollisionObject? These are not standard classes.

Comment: @Code-Guru They are from the "bullet" engine, just like the tags and the links in the post would suggest?

Comment: @Code-Guru: indeed it is!=)

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you should be able to control the color when overriding `btIDebugDraw::drawLine` and `btIDebugDraw::drawContactPoint`, as the last parameter to both is a `const btVector3&` representing red, green, and blue - from the class's comments, in a range of [0 .. 1].

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never.

```
const glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f); // Identiy
btTransform btTransf;
btTransf.setIdentity();
btTransf.setFromOpenGLMatrix(glm::value_ptr(transform));
btRigidBody* rb = new btRigidBody(0.0f, new btDefaultMotionState(btTransf), new btSphereShape(0.5f));
rb->setCustomDebugColor(btVector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // Red collision
```